# Create element unique id with addEventListener (not jquery)

Tags: javascript, loops, click, addeventlistener

I have this:

```
var divProducthere= document.getElementById('divProducthere'); //div 
var productbutton = document.getElementById('productbutton'); // button

  productbutton.addEventListener('click',prodElement);

   function prodElement(){
       for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        var selectProduct = document.createElement('select');
        selectProduct.id = 'r'+i;
        divProducthere.appendChild(selectProduct);

}
```

this does not work for me, because I just need to create the elements with the click event, one by one, but assigning unique id to each of the created elements

Comment: Why do you need an ID at all?

Comment: Because i need to create an element every time I click on the button

Comment: But why do those elements need IDs?

Comment: once the dynamical elements are added, I need to identify them to make a submit.

Comment: If you store references to these elements in any data structure, it could be more efficient than finding them by ID every time. `document.createElement` then returns precisely what you'll need.

Comment: each of these elements (products) will be stored in the database independently, not as a single form

Comment: @rafaelAntoniocorzoGutierrez When you submit forms, it uses the `name`, not the `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the counter in a global variable.

```
var select_counter = 0;
function prodElement() {
    select_counter++;
    var selectProduct = document.createElement('select');
    selectProduct.id = 'r'+select_counter;
    divProducthere.appendChild(selectProduct);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique id like this:

```js
function uniqId(length = 6) {
  return (Math.random().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36)).substr(2, length);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(uniqId(parseInt(Math.max(2, Math.random() * 10))))
}
```